# Error when calling locationInView:

Tags: ios, events, appkit

Please help me. I have next issue:

I want to handle `touchesMoved:` event in my subclass of `UIViewController` (I have an view with view controller), but when I call `[aTouch locationInView:self]` got an exception `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MySomeSubclass convertPoint:fromView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdc64000'`.

Can anyone explain me, why I got that exception and how to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to do `[aTouch locationInView:self.view]` ?

Comment: Ohh, thanks! Yes, I forgot `self.view`. It's too much work today.

Comment: I added the official answer, please mark as correct if this fixed your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be: `[aTouch locationInView:self.view]`